# UDP datagram is sent but never received

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I made two different java classes, for a client and for a server, with send and receive methods in each. According to the task, I had to make server-to-client connection via `DatagramPacket`  and client-to-server via `DatagramChannel`. The last one works great, but I have trouble with datagrams -- they are sent from the server and never received on the client. What's wrong?

```
public class TransferClient implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 26L;
    public TransferClient() {

    }

    public void send(Command com) throws IOException {
        SocketAddress socketAddressChannel = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 1);
        DatagramChannel datagramChannel=DatagramChannel.open();
        ByteBuffer bb;
        datagramChannel.connect(socketAddressChannel);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(com);
        oos.flush();
        bb=ByteBuffer.wrap(baos.toByteArray(),0, baos.size());
        datagramChannel.send(bb,socketAddressChannel);
        baos.close();
        oos.close();
    }

    public Command receive() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(2029);
        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
        DatagramPacket inputPacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024],1024, address);
        s.receive(inputPacket);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputPacket.getData());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        return (Command) ois.readObject();
    }
}

public class TransferServer {
    public TransferServer(){

    }

    public void send(Command com) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        byte[] buffer;
        oos.writeObject(com);
        oos.flush();
        buffer=baos.toByteArray();
        SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost",2029);
        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
        DatagramPacket outputPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length,address);
        s.send(outputPacket);
    }


    public Command receive() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            SocketAddress socketAddressChannel = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 1);
            DatagramChannel datagramChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
            datagramChannel.bind(socketAddressChannel);
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
            datagramChannel.receive(bb);
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bb.array());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            Command command;
            System.out.println(ois.available());
            command =(Command) ois.readObject();
            datagramChannel.close();
            ois.close();
            bais.close();
            return command;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ports below 1024 are protected. Looks like you're using very low numbers.

Comment: Oh, gush, I changed the ports, but it didn't help. However, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the port on which to bind your `DatagramSocket` in order to receive your data. Otherwise it will bind to the first available port found on your machine.

And you don't need the `SocketAddress` here, but you do need to take account of the actual received packet length.

See [java.net.DatagramSocket Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket())
In the `receive()` method of your `TransferClient` class:

```
public Command receive() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(2029); //Add your port Here

    DatagramPacket inputPacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024],1024);
    s.receive(inputPacket);
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputPacket.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
    return (Command) ois.readObject();
}
```

Comment: But then it throws BindException: Address already in use: bind. To clarify the situation: at first I send data from a client to a server and then -- from the server to the client.

Comment: Be sure not to set the DatagramSocket's port in your server's `send()` method, that could be the cause of the exception.

Comment: I don't set it in the server's send() method.

Comment: Actually I set it in the sending Package. Can this exception be caused by that?

Comment: You have to set it in the sent **Datagram**  to set the destination. Maybe try closing/disconnecting the sockets at the end of your `receive()` methods (see the documentation in the answer).

Comment: I found out it happens only if something had been sent from a client to a server BEFORE sending back, from a server to a client.

Comment: I think it is because you are opening two sockets on the same port (one on the client and one on the server). Try using a different port on one of them.

Comment: It is because you are opening a socket every time you enter this method, and never closing it. You should create the socket *before* entering the method, *once*, and close it when you've completely finished with it.

Comment: I'm not aware of Stack Overflow's customs, so should I upload the working version of the code now?

Comment: You can edit the solution into your question if you like, but don't obliterate the code that led to the question, otherwise the whole thing becomes pointess.